# how to open the info window after search and pan to the position on google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, search, infowindow

I try to open the info window after search and pan to the position on google map. Can someone help me? Thank you.

```
var availableTags = [];
for (i=0;i<mapLocationsJSON.length;i++){
    availableTags[i]=mapLocationsJSON[i].title;
}

//This is the autocomplete text field
$(function() {
    $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
});

//Insert the function here for what you want it to do when you search
function myFunc(searchTerm){
    var validSearch=false;
    var markerNumber;

    //Check to see if the term they searched for matches any of the locations in the map data
    for (i=0;i<mapLocationsJSON.length;i++){
        if(searchTerm==mapLocationsJSON[i].title){
            validSearch=true;
            markerNumber=i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(validSearch){
        //Pan to the position and zoom in.
        map.panTo(markers[markerNumber].getPosition());
        map.setZoom(7);

        //I'm not sure how to open the info window.... ?
        //infowindow.open(map,markers[markerNumber]);
    }else{
        //if the data doesn't match a term, ask them to search again. 
        alert("Please try again")
    };
}
```

What should I do to open info window after finish searching the location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a pre-existing click listener on the marker (you didn't include your code that defines the marker), the simplest way is:

```
if(validSearch){
        //Pan to the position and zoom in.
        map.panTo(markers[markerNumber].getPosition());
        map.setZoom(7);
        // click on the marker
        google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNumber],'click');
}else{
        //if the data doesn't match a term, ask them to search again. 
        alert("Please try again")
}
```